# Custom Logging of IBM cloud functions

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-functions

We want to know how we can enable custom logging to IBM cloud functions, till now we used to see the logs in IBM Cloud Log Analysis Service which is enabled by default in IBM cloud and now its getting deprecated in mid July.

We want to add additional logging to IBM cloud functions, Please let us know how we can do this .

Answer (score 0):

I would try adding an additional log appender to the standard logger for the log target that you want to use (logentries or splunk etc). Here's a link to the documentation that talks about tweaking the log settings: https://github.com/apache/openwhisk/blob/master/docs/logging.md

And this article does a good job describing how you can create a custom appender if your logging vendor provides one: https://www.baeldung.com/custom-logback-appender